# Printing specific items out of a list

Tags: python, list, printing

I'm wondering how to print specific items from a list *e.g.* given:

```
li = [1,2,3,4]
```

I want to print just the 3<sup>rd</sup> and 4<sup>th</sup> within a loop and I have been trying to use some kind of for-loop like the following:

```
for i in range (li(3,4)):
    print (li[i])
```

However I'm Getting all kinds of error such as:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple.
TypeError: list object is not callable
```

I've been trying to change `()` for `[]` and been shuffling the words around to see if it would work but it hasn't so far.

Answer (score 12):

Using slice notation you can get the sublist of items you want:

```
>>> li = [1,2,3,4]
>>> li[2:]
[3, 4]
```

Then just iterate over the sublist:

```
>>> for item in li[2:]:
...     print item
... 
3
4
```

Answer (score 3):

You should do:

```
for i in [2, 3]:
    print(li[i])
```

By `range(n)`, you are getting `[0, 1, 2, ..., n-1]`

By `range(m, n)`, you are getting `[m, m+1, ..., n-1]`

That is why you use `range`, getting a `list` of indices.

It is more recommended to use `slicing` like other fellows showed.

Comment: I don't like this much - unnecessary creation of a list that's discarded immediately afterwards, using element access when direct iteration over a slice is possible...it's not wrong, but it's not pythonic.

Comment: Agree! Just to illustrate why we use `range`.

Comment: nearly all computation is discarded immediately afterwards.
print(li[2:3]) works and is more pythonic.

Answer (score 1):

`li(3,4)` will try to call whatever `li` is with the arguments `3` and `4`. As a list is not callable, this will fail. If you want to iterate over a certain list of indexes, you can just specify it like that:

```
for i in [2, 3]:
    print(li[i])
```

Note that indexes start at zero, so if you want to get the `3` and `4` you will need to access list indexes `2` and `3`.

You can also slice the list and iterate over the lists instead. By doing `li[2:4]` you get a list containing the third and fourth element (i.e. indexes `i` with `2 <= i < 4`). And then you can use the for loop to iterate over those elements:

```
for x in li[2:4]:
    print(x)
```

Note that iterating over a list will give you the elements directly but not the indexes.