# Getting a specific value of a key in a dictionary?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary like this:

```
d = {'k1':[0.2,0.65,0.23], 'k2':[0.32,1.2,3.3], 'k3':[1.8,0.6,0.4], ...}
```

So, I want to get a list of the key and the second value of each key in a list. I have tried this code:

```
names = list(d.keys())
values = list(d.values())
```

The first line is correct and gives me the list of all keys, but the second line provides all the values, which is not what I needed. So I need only the second or the third value of each key. Any suggestions?

Comment: I do not understand your question. Do you need to get a list like this: [0.65, 1.2, 0.6,...]?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Printing specific items out of a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20609376/printing-specific-items-out-of-a-list)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterate over the `dict` and get the `v[1]` for each `key`, in a new `dict`:

```
d = {'k1':[0.2,0.65,0.23], 'k2':[0.32,1.2,3.3], 'k3':[1.8,0.6,0.4]}

print({k:v[1] for k,v in d.items()})
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
{'k1': 0.65, 'k2': 1.2, 'k3': 0.6}
```

Answer (score 2):

try:

```py
mylist = [(k, v[1]) for k, v in d.items()]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
{k:v[1] for k,v in d.items()}
```

Create a new `dict` with the second value from the list-value of the original `dict` using a dictionary comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

This will help you:

```
names = list(d.keys())
values = [v[1] for v in d.values()]
```

Answer (score 0):

This iterate key and values per key

```
for k,v in d.items():
    print("Key: %s" %k)
    print("Values: %s" %v)
    print("-"*8)
```

Comment: That's not what the user asked for.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> d = {'k1':[0.2,0.65,0.23], 'k2':[0.32,1.2,3.3], 'k3':[1.8,0.6,0.4]}
>>> np.array(list(d.values()))[:,1]
```

*Output:*

```
array([0.65, 1.2 , 0.6 ])
```

Answer (score 0):

d =  {k1:[0.2,0.65,0.23], k2:[0.32,1.2,3.3], k3:[1.8,0.6,0.4], ...}

1. for fetching only 2nd element from the values, Below code will print only 2nd elements of each key 
   example - [v[1] for k,v in d.iteritems()]
   prints [0.65,1.2,0.6]
2. for fetching key:value
   {k:v[1] for k,v in d.iteritems()}
   prints {'k1':0.65,'k2':1.2,'k3':0.6}
3. for fetching 2nd and 3rd element both , something like this can be done
   {k:[v[1],v[2]] for k,v in d.iteritems()}